# Password hashing within PHP not working

Tags: php, hash

I'm trying to create a password hash in a php file for a mini blog i'm creating, I have got to the stage where new user passwords are being hashed when a user registers, but when I test the new user login, i get an incorrect password error. Here is the code:-

```php
<?php

//require the public header which starts a session and connects to the database
require('header_public.php');
//3. If the form is submitted or not.
//3.1 If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
    //3.1.1 Assigning posted values to variables.
    $username = db_escape($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = db_escape($con, $_POST['password']);
    //3.1.2 Checking the values are existing in the database or not
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    $resultPassword = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    //getting the hashed password from the database
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($resultPassword)){
        $hashPassword = $row['password'];
    }

    //3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
    if ($count == 1 && password_verify($password, $hashPassword)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

        //Get the user type for use in other areas of the site
        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $admin = $row['admin'];

        }
        //assign userid to session array
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
    }else{
        //3.1.3 If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be shown with an error message.
        $fmsg = "Invalid Login Credentials.";
    }
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    //$username = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "Welcome back  " . $username;
    echo " </br> You will be redirected to the members area in less than 5 seconds";
    header( "Refresh:3; summary_page.php");
    echo "</br> <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}else{
//3.2 When the user visits the page first time, simple login form will be displayed.
?>
```

Grateful for any steer someone could provide. I think the issue is related to the starting the new session with the username, but can't be sure

Comment: Please show us the code that you are using to create and store the hashed password in your table as well as the column definition for the password field in your table.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the input before passing it to `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`, just pass $_POST['password'] directly, it is safe to do so. Then make sure the database field is `varchar(255)`.